# Lustre as a Chemical Property

Tags: physical-chemistry

In a text that I was reading, I found this paragraph on chemical properties:

> Chemical properties describe the ability of a substance to form new substances, either by reaction with other substances or by decomposition. For example, a chemical property of the element iron is its tendency to react with oxygen from air in the presence of water to form rust (a compound composed of iron and oxygen). The conversion of rust back into iron and oxygen is a difficult chemical process. **In some cases, chemical properties relate to the absence of specific changes. For example, a chemical property of the element gold is that it maintains its lustrous appearance because it resists rusting or tarnishing.**

However, other sources have cited lustre as a physical property. I want to know what is the correct answer, or, if the question is wrong itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lustre is a physical property, yes but the statement in the paragraph explains that the lustrous nature of Gold(which is a physical property) is preserved due to the chemical inertness of the element.

Generally, active metals lose their lustre(shine) since they react with the moisture, oxygen and other gases like hydrogen sulphide and carbon dioxide. This is a chemical property.

So, its absence in the element Gold is known as inertness towards corrosion.